# List of current folders in VS Code instance from command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line

Is there a way to get the list of all folders currently open in VS Code window from command line?

The command `code --help` shows these two related options, but not any for listing:

```
  -a --add <folder>    Add folder(s) to the last active window.
  -r --reuse-window    Force to open a file or folder in an already opened window.
```